# Traversing arbitrarily nested lists

Tags: python, list, recursion, list-comprehension, nested-lists

So x is the value I am looking for in the nested list t. I understand what happens throughout the code and the list comprehension, what I do not understand is at what point does [5] become path, then [3,5] becomes path and finally [1,3,5] gets returned to show the final path of values.

```
def findPath(t, x):
    if t[0] == x:
        return [t[0]]
    for path in [findPath(branch, x) for branch in t[1:]]:
        if path:
            return [t[0]] + path

t = [1, [3, [4], [5]], [2]]

findPath(t, 5)
#returns [1,3,5]
findPath(t, 2)
#returns [1 ,2]
```

Here is a link that helped me understand step by step, I just don't understand how the list becomes the path ultimately returning [t[0]] + path. https:// goo.gl/ZRrZv7

Answer (score 1):

Imagine `t` to be a tree structure, like this:

```
    [1, [3, [4], [5]], [2]]

             ||

              1
            /   \
           3     2
         /  \
        4    5
```

You keep traversing down the tree, exploring each path. Dead ends return `None`, so `if path` is `False` for dead ends. When you find the path you're looking for, (example, 5), then `[5]` is returned. `path` is not `None`, so `if path` is `True`, so you return `t[0]` + `[5]` = `[3, 5]`. Similarly, in the level above, `[3, 5]` is not `None`, so you return `t[0]` + `[3, 5]` = `[1, 3, 5]`. If no path is found, then nothing is returned anywhere (only `None` is returned, to be exact).

The same reasoning follows for your second example.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't follow the link because I generally don't follow links that aren't for commonly used websites, but here's an explanation of what happens:

```
t = [1, [3, [4], [5]], [2]]
```

At stack level (`0`) we call:

```
findPath(t, 5)
```

This evaluates to:

```
findPath([1, [3, [4], [5]], [2]], 5)
```

We start stack level (`0`) by checking `t[0]`. We'll represent this with the notation List(`<stack level>`: `<current index>`), which here gives us (`0: 0`).

At this point, `t[0]` is not equal to `x`, so we fall through the un-specified else condition of the if statement and move to the next iteration of the for loop. We increment the index in the current stack level (`0: 1`) and add another stack level (`1`), which gives us a state of (`0: 1`, `1: 0`), where we call:

```
findPath([3, [4], [5]], 5)
```

Again, t[0] is not equal to `x`, so we increment the index in the current stack level to (`0: 1`, `1: 1`) and add another stack level to try (`0: 1`, `1: 1`, `2: 0`), which makes us call:

```
findPath([4], 5)
```

Here `t[0]` is not equal to `x` and `t[1:]` is empty, so we go back down a stack level to stack level (`1`) and pick up where we left off; we increment the counter at this level to (`0: 1`, `1: 2`) and then add a stack level, which gives us (`0: 1`, `1: 2`, `2: 0`). This makes us call:
    findPath([5], 5)

Aha! Now `t[0]` is equal to `x` at the highest stack level, so we construct `[t[0]]`; this evaluates to `[5]`. Then we go back down a stack level and pick up where we left off; we were at (`0: 1`, `1: 2`). Now findPath returned a value so we're in the if condition for the first time instead of falling through to the next iteration. So we take `t[0]` at the current stack level and append the return value to it; this evaluates to appending `[5]` to `[3]`, which gives us `[3,5]`.

Next, we fall back down again to (`0: 1`) and repeat the process; now we need to append `[3,5]` to `[1]`, so we get `[1,3,5]`.

Is this starting to make sense? I made a up a weird notation here because I don't want to spend time drawing pictures, but to really understand this you should draw out the stack levels for yourself.